# How to extend binary line to the borders of an image in python?

Tags: python, mask, image-segmentation

I want to make sure that any binary line like the one shown in the example reaches the borders of the image. How can I do that? I've tried to dilate and erode but it won't solve the problem if there is a big gap between the end of the line and the border of the image.

[image]

Comment: Can you share expected image?

Comment: I've included an example with the expected result. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code works for provided image. May not work for others. I'm using `copy-paste` approach.

```
from PIL import Image

# Create "patch" image
image = Image.open('image.png')
width, height = image.size
start_position = None
end_position = None
line_width = 0
line_width_count = True
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        r, g, b = image.getpixel((x, y))
        if all([r, g, b]) and not start_position:
            start_position = x, y

        if line_width_count and all([r, g, b]) and start_position:
            line_width += 1

        if line_width and all([not r, not g, not b]):
            line_width_count = False

        if all([r, g, b]):
            end_position = x, y

patch = Image.open('image.png')
patch = patch.crop((start_position[0], start_position[1], end_position[0], end_position[1]))
patch_width, patch_height = patch.size

# Add top patches
end_pos_x = start_position[0] - patch_width + line_width * 2
end_pos_y = start_position[1] - patch_height + line_width
for i in range(5):
    image.paste(patch, (end_pos_x, end_pos_y))
    end_pos_x -= patch_width - line_width * 2
    end_pos_y -= patch_height - line_width

# Add bottom patches
end_pos_x = end_position[0]-line_width*2
end_pos_y = end_position[1]-line_width
for i in range(5):
    image.paste(patch, (end_pos_x, end_pos_y))
    end_pos_x += patch_width - line_width * 2
    end_pos_y += patch_height - line_width

image.save('result.png')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your solution solves my problem.